# Singleton in Linux with Shared Modules and Static Memory Access

Tags: c++, linux, memory

I have a process I am starting that is loading in multiple shared libraries. Some of the code in these shared libraries is the same (e.g. common files) and is using a singleton setup. e.g.

```cpp
class MySingleton
{
  public:
    static MySingleton& GetInstance()
    {
      static MySingleton singleton;
      return singleton;
    }

    // ...
  private:
    // ...
}
```

I have run into a problem now where this `MySingleton` class is only being initialized once and being shared between the modules in memory (since they are being loaded into the same process). This seems to be a Linux specific problem, as I have had no issues with this on Mac OS or Windows where the application has been functioning fine.

To further emphasize/clarify the question, I have the following code for instance:

```cpp
// module 1
MySingleton::GetInstance().DoSomething(); // GetInstance() returns 0xABCDEFF
```

```cpp
// module 2
MySingleton::GetInstance().DoSomethingElse(); // GetInstance() also returns 0xABCDEFF
```

My question is the following: Is there a way to force Linux/the shared modules to have independent static memory pools? Or am I at the mercy of the Linux operating system and how it decides to implement this?

In my case I am using this Singleton all over my code for a logging system...and it would be extremely inconvenient to go and have to modify this all over the place. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a few days (I know this question is only 30 minutes old, but I did finally find the solution)...I found what I was missing and doing on macOS but not on Linux.

I added the following extra compile flags to my common code and everything fell into place perfectly like it was on macOS `-fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fvisibility=hidden`.

With these extra flags in place, the code is separate from each other and no longer overlapping in memory.